# Integrating Android Code in Codenamone

Tags: android, codenameone

I would like to know how to modify android code to use in the native interface of codenameone. That is how to modify the activities with layouts and and handling the life cycles from android to codenameone. An example would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html

I have also taken reference from this code and it works fine to use native code for android.

Comment: I've watched the video but my problem is I have a working android code with activities and layout. How do i integrate that in codenameone handling the lifecylces and layouts. If there's any modification to be done.

Comment: Create an Android native library project and create an ARR follow the instructions for working with the ARR in the developer guide https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Thanks would be checking it out right away